# Sum up two columns from two different tables

Tags: excel, vba

I really need your help, I want to sum up the not empty cells in every appearance of the header of the column.

For example:

```
     |111|222|333|111|444|222|555
```

---

```
aaa  |2  |2  |2  |2  |2  |2  |2    
bbb  |   |2  |2  |2  |2  |2  |2  
ccc  |   |   |2  |   |2  |2  |  
ddd  |2  |   |   |2  |   |2  |  
eee  |2  |   |2  |   |   |   |2
```

I want the result look like this:

```
    |111|222|333|444|555
    --------------------
    |6  |6  |4  |3  |3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean count the number of non-empty cells?

Comment: yes, the vba code is great' this is exactly what i need.

Comment: can you accept the answer if it works for you? It will help others out if they are searching a similar problem

Comment: It works! I changed the question a little bit.I need to do another step after receiving the table. I need to combine it with "table 2",  so i get the "result table".. can you help me with that pls?

Comment: It's probably best to create a new question and state that it relates to this question (i.e. add a link to this question). It's cleaner that way, especially now that you have accepted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. You may need to update range references. It outputs the summary on a separate worksheet.

```
Sub UserNameCount()
Dim headers As Range, header As Range, countRng As Range, col As Long

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set headers = Range("A1:G1")
col = 1

For Each header In headers
    Set countRng = Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.Offset(5, 0)) //update the '5' depending on the number of rows you have

    If Not dict.Exists(header.Value) Then
        dict.Add header.Value, WorksheetFunction.CountA(countRng)
    Else
        dict.Item(header.Value) = dict.Item(header.Value) + WorksheetFunction.CountA(countRng)
    End If
Next header

For Each v In dict.Keys
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Cells(1, col) = v
        .Cells(2, col) = dict.Item(v)
        col = col + 1
    End With
Next

Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

In the bottom of the sheet, use a COUNTA formula to count nonblanks from each column.

```
         |111|222|333|111|444|222|555
 -------------------------------------
    aaa  |2  |2  |2  |2  |2  |2  |2    
    bbb  |   |2  |2  |2  |2  |2  |2  
    ccc  |   |   |2  |   |2  |2  |  
    ddd  |2  |   |   |2  |   |2  |  
    eee  |2  |   |2  |   |   |   |2  
  COUNTA |3  |2  |4  |3  |3  |4  |3
```

Paste special/transpose the header row and the COUNTA row into a new sheet.

```
  Header | COUNTA
 -----------------
    111  | 3
    222  | 2
    333  | 4
    111  | 3
    444  | 3
    222  | 4
    555  | 3
```

Now make a pivot table with column values "Header" and sum the COUNTA formula to get your result.

If you don't want to use a pivot table, paste the header values into a new sheet, remove duplicates, and use a SUMIF formula to get the totals for each header value.

Comment: Copy header values, remove duplicates, and use the formula =SUMIF(Range, Criteria, Sum_range). For example, =SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$8,A2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$8) where the data table is on Sheet1.